# How to project a n-dimensional point onto a 2-D subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Here is a n-dimensional space:
There's a point

$P (p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n)$

And two orthogonal vectors that determines a 2-D plane/subspace D

$v (v_1,v_2, \dots ,v_n)$
$w (w_1,w_2, \dots ,w_n)$

How do I project the point $P$ onto the 2-D subspace D that is determined by vector $v$ and $w$?

Comment: $\Pi_D P = \frac{\langle P, w\rangle}{\langle w,w\rangle} w + \frac{\langle P, v\rangle}{\langle v,v\rangle} v$

Comment: $\langle P, w\rangle = \sum_i p_iw_i$, the inner product of $P$ and $w$.

Comment: @martini : If I'm not mistaken, what you've written works if $v$ and $w$ are mutually orthogonal, but not otherwise.

Comment: Three upvotes for "martini"'s comment!  Does no one else see the error in it?

Comment: @Michael, $v$ and $w$ are stated to be orthogonal in the question.

Comment: Thank you guys. Both of the methods work!

Comment: @Hi271 when $v, w$ are orthogonal, then $M^T M = I$ in  Michael's answer, and the formula simplify to martini's comment.

Comment: OK, I missed that point.  @JenniferDylan : You won't get $I$ unless $v,w$ are unit vectors, but you get a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you know matrices, this will do it: Regard $P$, $v$, and $w$ are column vectors.  Let $M$ be the matrix whose two columns are $v$ and $w$.  It's an $n\times2$ matrix.  (By the way, you shouldn't use capital $N$ and lower-case $n$ as if they were synonymous.  Mathematical notation is case-sensitive.)  Then $M^TM$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix, which is invertible if the vectors $v$, $w$ are linearly independent.  The matrix $M(M^TM)^{-1}M^T$ is and $n\times n$ matrix of rank $2$.  The vector $M(M^TM)^{-1}M^T P$ is the projection that you seek.

**"Usage note":** Once upon a time a highly respected and moderately famous mathematician told me that $M(M^TM)^{-1}M^T$ is the identity matrix.  Apparently he was assuming $M$ was a *square* matrix.  I have a bold hypothesis, which I haven't checked empirically: "Pure" mathematicians tacitly assume matrices are square; "applied" mathematicians don't.